# Has the Key value (Set-Cookie) in the model-derivative v2 response header changed?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, forge

We are using model-derivative v2 from the following URL.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeUrn-signedcookies-GET/

The Key value in the response header is "Set-Cookie". But in reality, "set-cookie" is returned.
Was this change announced anywhere?　Or is it a glitch?

The Key value of the response header is "set-cookie".
Since Autodesk maintenance on February 24, 2024, it was changed to "set-cookie".